# Create checksum from base64 or raw data?

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, base64, checksum

In my project, I need to transfer image via API. Before transfer, I'm encoding raw image data with `base64` so I can use it in JSON request. What I want to do is add checksum of file to request so I can test on my API side if file was transfered successfully.

My question is - should I calculate checksum before or after base64?

```
// Client
$checksum = md5($rawImageData);
$base64ImageData = base64_encode($rawImageData);

// API
$receivedBase64 = $_POST['base64ImageData'];
$receivedChecksum = $_POST['checksum'];
$imageData = base64_decode($receivedBase64);
$actualChecksum = md5($imageData);

if ($receivedChecksum != $actualChecksum) {
   // Image not transfered correctly.
}
```

Or should I at first encode data with `base64`, then calculate md5 checksum and on API side, compare it with checksum of received base64? Or it doesn't matter and both solutions have same reliability? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a checksum? If you are using HTTP over TCP/IP, which has all sorts of checksums built in already, then you won't get bad data because of the network.

Comment: You should checksum before any data manipulation has happened.. always. This will ensure that nothing can obscure your results

Comment: checksum before base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question isn't really a REST question, or a php question...

If you were going to start transforming data to then send and then reverse these transformations, It would generally make sense to checksum at the very ends.

You do also need to keep in mind that HTTP will offer a fair bit of protection/correction for you. I'd be inclined to say don't even bother with the checksum. From the description of your uses case, it doesn't sound like you really need to add a checksum.